# C++ Class()::a(3){} meaning of ::a(3)

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Somewhere in my pdf lessons I encounter this:

```
class Class
{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
         Class()::a(3){};
```

Um I don't get, what's the meaning of ::a(3) next to the constructor and before brackets? We are new to C++ and haven't been taught this yet so if anyone could help... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an error.

If it were

```
Class() : a(3){};
//      |
//  single colon
```

it would be an initialization list, which initializes the member `a` with the value `3`. (provided you remove the `1` after the class name).

Comment: and may I ask something last really quick? so Class():a(3){} equals to Class() {a=3;} ???

Comment: @user3265784 No, it isn't. `Class():a(3){}` will set an initial value before construction. Most useful for initializing member classes that do not have a default constructor.